# Set Default Day Name Start Sunday in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$sunday = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('sunday this week'));      
echo $sunday;
```

> Output : 01-03-2020
>
> but output will be : 24-02-2020

Comment: What is your expected output?  24-02-2020 is Monday! not Sunday!

Comment: can you explain the question clearly so that we can answer the question much easily.

Comment: my my default week - mon to sun, but i want to sun to sat. working in codeigniter if i get first week date in case of return value of 24-02-2020 but it will be 23-02-2020, because it is mon to sun formate but i want san to sat formate in codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience of CodeIgniter, but check if you can use Carbon to achieve the same

```
$en = Carbon::now()->locale('en_US');
echo $en->startOfWeek(Carbon::Sunday)->format('d-m-Y');
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

You can see the official documentation here: [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Did you import the Carbon class using the namespace in you php file?

Comment: i used Carbon library and done easily, carbon is specially use in laravel but we can also use in codeigniter ,, thanks @keshari Nandan